# GoDaddy outbound SSH with Git clone issue

Tags: git, ssh, permissions, clone

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.jpedersonconsulting.com/getting-git-on-godaddy/) on how to enable git on a GoDaddy server.  Only when I reached the bottom did I notice the mention about GoDaddy blocking outbound SSH access when doing something like a clone command.

Sure enough, I get an error when trying to perform a clone with a remote repository.

```
fatal: cannot exec 'ssh': Permission denied
fatal: unable to fork
```

I've triple checked my ssh key on the remote repo as well.  I still keep getting this same error.  Has anyone seen else seen this issue?  Does anyone have a resolution?

Comment: Did you try using HTTPS instead of SSH? Something similar to: `git clone https://therepo.com/repo.git`. If you can't use HTTPS, then you might need to switch to a new server.

Comment: This much works.  The downside is there's no way to have the server's remember passwords using this protocol, which is necessary for setting up auto-depoyment (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: Good point. I think you may be right. Unfortunately there's nothing you can do on that server to get around it. I would recommend using a different VPS/server that doesn't have such a restriction on SSH.

Answer (score 5):

You check the keys on the remote repo all day long, the issue isn't on the remote side, but on GoDaddy side (where you do the `git clone`).

If ssh is blocked, you can forget about ssh urls for your git repos (unless you put in place some kind of [HTTP tunneling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel), but that might also be explicitly prohibited by GoDaddy policies).

Https url remain the only solution (even if you have to [setup an Apache on the remote side](http://lightyearsoftware.com/2012/01/git-https-repository-access-control/))

Answer (score 1):

One why would be to

git config --global http.sslVerify false

Comment: That has no effect on either allowing access thru ssh or avoiding prompt of password thru https